# Windows can't see I'm online

Tags: windows-10, internet

I'm running Win10, and whenever I start a Windows application (Mail, Store, etc.) I receive an error message saying that I don't have a connection. I obviously have a connection - I'm able to get here, so I'm online. But when I started up Mail and tried to add an account, I got an error:
[image]
[image]
I picked Google (for gmail), and...
[image]
Why isn't Windows seeing that I'm connected? This has happened before, with Store and other apps.
[image]
So what's wrong with this?

**Output of `ipconfig /all`:**

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mycomputer
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Belkin

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6914:9f49:78c1:f69f%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.8(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, February 24, 2017 9:37:23 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, April 4, 2153 4:23:47 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 82854428
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.Belkin:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Try press Windows + R keys and then type in `wsreset.exe` and hit enter. See if that works. It resets the Windows store cache.

Comment: It's not only in Store, it's all Windows applications. So resetting Store probably won't help. Edit: it didn't help

Comment: do you have a proxy? Some browsers are able to use a different proxy setting than the global one. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. How do I check if I'm using a proxy?

Comment: If it's all applications then update your question and state that and update your question to include the output of "ipconfig /all".  Also include which build of 1607 yournuaing exactly

Comment: @Ramhound, it's all _Windows_ applications. Others, like Chrome, work fine.

Comment: If it's all Windows applications then Chrome shouldn't work.  What do consider to be a Windows application if Chrome isn't a Windows application.....Do you happen to mean UWP Applications?  It stands for (Universal Windows Platform) application

Comment: I think it's Windows Services issue. Go to the Services and make sure of Network Store Interface Service is running and set to automatic. Restarting it may also fix the issue. (if it helps).

Comment: is DNS client service running? apps require that service to have Internet acess

Comment: @Ramhound, I mean Windows applications like those that come default with Windows, like Store, Edge, Mail, Weather, etc.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Stop calling those applications like are officially "UWP Applications" an application refers to any program you have installed on your PC

Comment: again, is the DNS client service running or not?

Comment: @magicandre1981, the dns service is running.

Comment: Okay, the problem was fixed by resetting Windows. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible reasons for this issue:

1. Security applications (e.g. antimalware or privacy tool) can create rules preventing apps from connecting. Check such apps and also check the Windows firewall rules. An example with ShutUp10 is below.

[image: disable app access]

2. [Windows 10 has some apps running continuously in the background](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/manage-windows-10-data-usage/). It's possible those apps have been turned off. In the Windows Control Panel, Privacy, Background Apps, try turning them on.
3. [It could be a Windows Socket issue,](http://www.windowswally.com/what-to-do-when-windows-10-apps-have-no-internet/) though that seems unlikely if other non-Windows applications (e.g. Firefox) are working. From a CMD prompt, run as Administrator, enter:

> netsh winsock reset catalog
>
> netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
>
> netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log

Answer (score 0):

Before getting too technical maybe just try:

"Complete Internet Repair 3.1.3.2852"

http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/complete_internet_repair.html

MajorGeeks is a safe site for downloads. I've been using them for about 10 (?) years.